# Performing if else check and setting value for later use. Looking for a cleaner way

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a customer parser to extract key parts of information from application logs to help with debugging issues.

Within the parser code I have lots of examples of the following sort of logic:

```
    String element = "";
    if( rawLogText.contains("RequestType") ) {
        element = "RequestType";
    }
    else if( rawLogText.contains("ResponseType") ) {
        element = "ResponseType";
    }

    if( element.equals("") ) {
        return;
    }
```

I feel like there is a cleaner way to do this sort of *check-set-return-process* logic.

**Can anyone come up with a cleaner way to do it?**

Here's what I had initially, but the multiple contains checks bugged me.

```
    String element = "";
    if( rawLogText.contains("RequestType") || rawLogText.contains("ResponseType") ) {
        if( rawLogText.contains("RequestType") ) {
            element = "RequestType";
        }
        else if( rawLogText.contains("ResponseType") ) {
            element = "ResponseType";
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
```

I'd also like to avoid ternary statements.

Comment: No bug as such, hence the code-quality tag. I'm interested to find out if there is indeed a cleaner way to code the logic presented within the question.

Comment: Can you provide an example of rawLogText? Maybe preprocessing a bit the log line could help to clean the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that @GuillermoMerino's solution is probably the best.

But if you repeated this pattern a lot in your parsing you could abstract it as a helper method; e.g.

```
public String matchWord(String input, String... words) {
   for (String word: word) do
       if (input.contains(word) ) {
           return word;
       }
   }
   return "";
}
```

and use it like this:

```
String element = matchWord(rawLogText, "RequestType", "ResponseType");
if (element.equals("")) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yep, looking through it, abstraction is probably for the best.

Answer (score 3):

What about this instead of checking `element.equals()`:

```
String element = null;
if( rawLogText.contains("RequestType") ) {
    element = "RequestType";
}
else if( rawLogText.contains("ResponseType") ) {
    element = "ResponseType";
} else {
    return;
}
//continue the process
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you put all the `types` in a string array:

```
 String[] possibleTypes = {"RequestType", "ResponseType"}; // and such
```

Now you can use a for loop to check and set value

```
 String element = ""
 for (String type : possibleTypes) {
     if (rawLogText.contains(type)) {
         element = type;
         break;
     }
 }

 if( element.equals("") ) {
    return;
 }
```